# AutoMapper - Map a base class to its derived class (with generics)

Tags: c#, automapper

What I'd like is to map a base class to an open-typed generic.

```
public class A
{
  public string Title {get; set;}
}

public class B<T> : A
{
  T Content {get; set;}
}
```

From here, I'd like to do something like:

```
var a = new A() { Title = "Fun" };
var b = mapper.Map<A, B<MyContentModel>>(a);
```

The result being, B with the Title populated, but the Content field ignored.  I've tried using the various examples provided on the official AutoMapper documentation without success; I think it's because source and destination are not equivalent in terms of the open typing.

Generally, the error I receive states that the mapping does not exist between A and B'1.  I have tried

```
CreateMap(typeof(A), typeof(B<>));
CreateMap<A, B<>>();
```

Short of mapping ever possible iteration of B, is there a way to handle this with the AutoMapper framework?

My workaround is to use a constructor, but I'd much prefer not to have to curate the ever-growing list of things mappable in A.

```
public class B<T>
{
  public B(A a) 
  {
    Title = a.Title;
  }
}
```